# How to pass variables to handlebars helpers

Tags: ember.js, template-engine

I'm create handlebars helper:

```
export default Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('if-eq', function(v1, v2, options) {
if (this.get(v1) === this.get(v2)) {
return options.fn(this);
}
return options.inverse(this);
});
```

And execute like this:

```
{{#each item in model.cons }}
{{#if-eq model.currentUser.id item.record_poster_id}}
<div class="td author current">{{model.currentUser.name}}</div>
{{else}}
<div class="td author remote">{{model.remoteUser.name}}</div>
{{/if-eq}}
{{/each}}
```

I recieved variables like text "model.currentUser.id", using this.get(v1) I can get value.
But this.get working only for model.currentUser.id and don't work for item.record_poster_id (maybe because it's variable from the loop)

QUESION: how i can pass variable by value?

ANSWER: [How to compare values in each?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25135721/how-to-compare-values-in-each)

Answer (score -2):

You *are* passing the variable's value, you're just accessing them incorrectly. Why are you using `this.get(v1)` to access the argument? Just use `v1`. It's already the value you passed in, you don't have to do anything special to it.

Also, I'm not sure if that Handlebars syntax will work. Ember might require you to do something like [this](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/a-way-to-let-users-define-custom-made-bound-if-statements/2583).

Comment: console.log(v1,v2); return value like this: "model.currentUser.id","item.record_poster_id"

Comment: My apologies, I should pay better attention. Your syntax is correct, your method call isn't. Use `helper` instead of `registerHelper`.

Comment: helper also not working: "Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: registerBoundHelper-generated helpers do not support use with Handlebars blocks."

Comment: That is the issue I linked to in my answer. I've never written a block helper before, so I'm not 100% sure of the syntax, but that thread should help you out.